# Arcpy SelectLayerByAttribute_management where_clause with LIKE not returning like values

Tags: python, arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am selecting 2 intersections from a shape file using info from a File Geodatabase Table. The values are very similar as shown in example at the bottom. I am using a LIKE in the statement but it is not returning values that should be there. It is rather lengthy but I'll try to cut it down.

```
    Whereclausefrom = '''"FULSTRT" LIKE '%{road}%' AND "FulStrt2" LIKE '%{fromst}%\''''.format(road=roadname, fromst=fromstreet)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('IntersectionPoints', 'temp_Intersection', Whereclausefrom)


    Whereclauseto = '''"FULSTRT" LIKE '%{road}%' AND "FulStrt2" LIKE '%{tost}%\''''.format(road=roadname, tost=tostreet)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('IntersectionPoints', 'temp_IntersectionTo', Whereclauseto)

    Num1 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("temp_Intersection").getOutput(0))
    Num2 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("temp_IntersectionTo").getOutput(0))
    Num = Num1 + Num2

    if Num1 < 1:
      Whereclausefrom2 = '''"FULSTRT" LIKE '%{fromst}%' AND "FulStrt2" LIKE '%{road}%\''''.format(road=roadname, fromst=fromstreet)
      arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('IntersectionPoints', 'temp_Intersection', Whereclausefrom2)
    if Num2 < 1:
      Whereclauseto2 = '''"FULSTRT" LIKE '%{tost}%' AND "FulStrt2" LIKE '%{road}%\''''.format(road=roadname, tost=tostreet)
      arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('IntersectionPoints', 'temp_IntersectionTo', Whereclauseto2)

    Num1 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("temp_Intersection").getOutput(0))
    Num2 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("temp_IntersectionTo").getOutput(0))
    Num = Num1 + Num2

    if Num != 2:
      brokenRecord()
      brokencount = brokencount + 1
      writeText("Record added to Failed Records. Next Record")

    else:

      ## rest of script if there is exactly 1 from and exactly 1 to selected
```

Comment: What kind of geodatabase is it? Personal geodatabases use a different SQL syntax than shapefiles or file geodatabases.

Comment: It is a File Geodatabase

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but you might want to inspect the line after `if Num1 < 1`. It's different from the other sql.

Comment: The typo is in Whereclauseto2. Thank you @Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 @Hornbydd

Instead of concatenating strings, you might find it easier to write, debug, and read strings if you use .format()

The following is equivalent:

```
'''"FULSTRT" LIKE '%{road}%' AND "FulStrt2" LIKE '%{fromst}%\''''.format(road=roadname, fromst=fromstreet)
```

Or if you prefer,

```
'''"FULSTRT" LIKE '%{0}%' AND "FulStrt2" LIKE '%{1}%\''''.format(roadname, fromstreet)
```

The final single quote needs to be escaped or it will be recognized as closing the string.

Comment: I used this but I am still having problems. I am wondering if it isn't my if statements. I'll edit and ask about that instead...maybe I'm missing something stupid in my logic.

Comment: @user2521341, is there any reason you are using the same sql statement in make feature layer after running it on select layer by attribute? You should only need to use make feature layer.

Comment: no I'm not all that familiar with arcpy and your comment makes sense and will save me some lines but I don't think that will change anything about not selecting all the correct intersections

Answer (score 1):

Your `whereclause` from is incorrect, it should be:

```
Whereclausefrom = '"FULSTRT" LIKE ' + "'%" + roadname + "%' AND " + '"FulStrt2" LIKE ' + "'%" + fromstreet + "%'"
```

The double quotes were enclosing "FULSTRT LIKE" and "FulStrt2 LIKE" when they should be enclosing the field name only.