# SelectLayerByAttribute_management - Python string syntax

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, select-by-attribute

I am having trouble getting my syntax correct, currently I have

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("SpatialSCRIMNet", "NEW_SELECTION", RtyF LIKE 'D%' OR RtyF = 'S1' )
```

RtyF is a defined attribute using GetParameterAsText, "SpatialSCRIMNet" has been created via MakeFeatureLayer_management

I have tried:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ('  "SpatialSCRIMNet", "NEW_SELECTION",' RtyF LIKE 'D%' OR RtyF = 'S1' ')
```

and as above but with "

Can somebody advise please?

Comment: I suspect that this may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68455/arcpy-selectlayerbyattribute-management-where-clause-with-like-not-returning-lik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested, but try this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("SpatialSCRIMNet", "NEW_SELECTION",'"' + RtyF + '" LIKE ' + "'D%' OR " + '"' + RtyF + '" = ' + "'S1'")
```

Comment: Thank you that works, can you elaborate on this a little please so I can get a better understanding of string quote syntax in the future

Comment: Check out some of these posts which describe the rules I use in various ways and scenarios: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=double+single+quote+user%3A115